# Create shortcut key to insert new row using Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, spreadsheet

Tried to create a macro in Excel to insert a row:

```
Sub InsertRow()
'
' InsertRow Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+I
'
    Selection.EntireRow.Insert
End Sub
```

However, this does not insert a new row without first manually selecting a row.

Every solution I've found requires that a row be highlighted before inserting a new row.

See also: http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Excel_2010.html

How would you create a shortcut key (e.g., <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+J</kbd>) to highlight the current row and insert a new row?

Thank you!

### Update

Looks like <kbd>Shift+Space</kbd> highlights the current row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution...

1. Create a macro:

   ```
   Sub InsertRow()
   '
   ' InsertRow Macro
   '
   ' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
   '
       ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
       Selection.EntireRow.Insert
   End Sub
   ```
2. Assign the macro to a keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the insert row command in the quick access toolbar and calling it with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Number</kbd>?

You could also use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> for your first insert and then <kbd>F4</kbd> to repeat the insert, i.e. insert a new row above your selection (no need to select the whole row first). You can move your selection around and still use it.

Comment: The Alt-I R is slower than Ctrl+Shift+J because there is a key release that must happen first. The Alt-Number might work; I have a funny feeling it would prompt for the number of rows to enter, though.

Comment: Shift+Space / Ctrl+Shift+=

Comment: Yes, those work, but I'm looking for a single shortcut, not two shortcuts in combination.

Comment: For example, hold down `Ctrl+Shift` and type `J` as often as needed; it's very fast.

Comment: If you want to do it often, just use F4\

Comment: F4 is pretty close; the problem is that the functionality of F4 changes depending on the last command, so I'd have to remember to perform Alt+I R first. I was looking for a command key (like Ctrl+S) that "just works."

Comment: Then use a macro set on a shortcut. IMO not really worth it, but YMMV.